# Storing function call results for later referall

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I've been trying to read as much as I can about javascript callbacks and jquery deferred objects but apparently things just aren't clicking for me. It seems to make a vague amount of sense when I read through it and practice examples, but when I try to apply it to my specific problem, I'm just hitting a wall. If anyone can understand what I'm trying to do and offer ideas, it would be much appreciated!

Here's some existing code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    firstFunction();
    secondFunction(); 
});
```

For the sake of keeping things simple here, I won't get into what firstFunction() and secondFunction() do, but suffice it to say that they both perform asynchronous work.

Here's my problem: 
firstFunction() is dependent on the document being ready so needs to be inside $(document).ready(function() { }. secondFunction() isn't dependent on $(document).ready(function(), but should only execute after firstFunction has completed. I'm hoping to do all the computation for secondFunction() before the $(document).ready(function() { } block, but only execute it after firstFunction() has completed. This way firstFunction and secondFunction will execute in a more visually seamless manner. So basically, I'd like to do something like the following pseudo code:

```
var deferredSecondFunction = secondFunction().compute().defer(); //perform computation for secondFunction but defer execution

$(document).ready(function() {
    firstFunction().done.execute(deferredSecondFunction().execute()); //finally execute secondFunction once firstFunction has completed. 
});
```

Does anyone know if this is even possible? An important caveat is that I need to do this without the Javascript Promise object, since, for reasons outside the scope of this question, the webkit I'm working with is an old version. If anyone could help me understand this it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The code shown uses a callback function and a self-invoking anonymous JavaScript function such has:

```
var calculatedObject;
(function(){
    // Will be executed as soon as browser interprets it.
    // write code here & save your calculations/operations
    calculatedObject = { ... };
})();

function firstFunction(callback){
    // Do stuff
    callback();
}

function secondFunction(){
   // Do more stuff
   // Use your calculations saved in the calculated object.
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    firstFunction(secondFunction);
});
```

This way the second function will only be called at the end of the first one.

Comment: Thanks, but how would this ensure that the computation for secondFunction is done before the document is ready? Or is that not even possible?

Comment: When you say computation do you mean that the second function exists? Or do you actually have 3 functions one of which you would like to execute before the doc ready?

Comment: Both functions already exist, but the execution of second function can perform independently of the doc being ready. But I only actually want to call that function after firstFunction, which is dependent on the doc being ready. Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Basically is there a way to run secondFunction in the background while the doc is getting ready and then only call it after firstFunction completes?

Comment: Well it depends on what you are trying to achieve. It seems to me that you might have big calculations that you want to compute but only execute when the firstFunction is done. You could have a third function which would be where you  would do the calculations and store the values in a javascript object that you can then use in the other functions.

Comment: You're basically saying you have a `secondFunction_A` and `secondFunction_B` which have different requirements: A is independent of the document being ready, while B is dependent on the document by the transitive property (B relies on `firstFunction` which relies on document being ready). So as @Alex was saying, you can break your computation into a separate function if you deem it necessary

Answer (score 0):

you can use a callback..

```
function f1(){
    //do some stuff
}

function f2(callback){
    // do some async stuff
    callback();
}

f2(f1);
```

this example passes one function to another function. the second function then calls the first whenever it's ready.

Comment: I think I'm still confused on how this would perform the computation of f2 before $(document).ready?

Comment: it dosn't. it doesn't do anything until `f2` calls it.